# Windows form application checkbox layout

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am working on my windows form application using c#. I have a question about my list of checkbox layout. Let say my user can select an item in the combo box which contains a list of application name fetched from a database.  When the user selected the application, the user can choose a class, and it's grade. For example Grade 9A, Grade 9b, Grade 10e. From Grade 9 to 12 and class A to B. What I did is I add a bunch of checkboxes to do it. I am not sure if this is a good way to do this. It is because when I select an application, which student who is in that grade and class will be checked. For example, if my first application has student who can use that application will be checked by their grade and class such as if student in Grade 9A, 9B and 11D use that application, then check box 9, 11 and Grade will be checked, and A, B, D will be checked from class. At first I thought this is a good layout, but then I realized that the user may get confused because they don't know the exact match. they may be thinking "oh it may be Grade 9 with A, B, D. and Grade 11 with A, B, D" but, in fact, it is not. I am not sure a good way to fix this issue. 
Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

For example

```
Grade:

 [] 9 []10  []11  []12 
Class

[]A  []B    []C   []D    []E
```

Comment: For good UI, only legitimate choices (and ALL legitimate choices) should be available to the user.  It sounds like you need to revisit.  Maybe draw it out before you code it.

Comment: Hi Steve, I have drew it out before, but this is what I came up with, but I am not really sure how I can make it more readable

Comment: Based on that simple UI, if 9 and 11 are checked, and A, B and D are checked, it doesn't make sense that the query would be (9A or 9B or 11D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a UI like this may be better:

```
 [x]9 [x]A [x]B [x]C [ ]D [ ]E 

[ ]10 [ ]A [ ]B [ ]C [ ]D [ ]E 

[x]11 [ ]A [x]B [ ]C [ ]D [ ]E 

[x]12 [ ]A [ ]B [ ]C [ ]D [ ]E
```

Then the SQL statement would look something like:

```
where Grade = 9 and Class in (A, B, C) or Grade = 11 and Class in (B) or Grade = 12
```

So then the checkboxes A to E are only available if the corresponding grade is checked.

Comment: @DragonBorn If you are displaying the results in a `DataGridView` then you may want to look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33786/DataGridView-Filter-Popup. That way, only a simple set of UI controls is required for the initial SQL query, and the user can filter the dgv as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I will display the results to DataGridView, because I am thinking to just export the data to an excel file